# Не изменяются значения Width и Height

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Пытаюсь изменить width и height у Ellipse - не изменяется.
Пытаюсь изменить width и height через анимацию - изменяется.
Почему так?
Код:

```
 Ellipse el = ((item as Grid).Children[0] as Ellipse);
 //DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
 //el.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.WidthProperty, da);
 //el.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.HeightProperty, da);
 el.Width = value;
 el.Height = value;
```

Comment: А к эллипсу перед тем, как напрямую изменить значения, применяется анимация? Проблема в том, что по умолчанию анимация удерживает значение свойства, то есть блокирует его ручное изменение. Нужно или запустить другую анимация, как вы и делаете (рабочий способ), или сбросить текущую, перед тем, как вручную выставлять. Для этого нужно запустить анимацию с null-анимацией. Короче, напишите `el.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.WidthProperty, null);` и `el.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.HeightProperty, null);`, перед ручным выставление свойства.

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо за объяснение.